# Facebook: Change the description/title that appears in a facebook post when I post a URL

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I am using a PHP script to post a URL to a fan page that I am an admin of, but the contents of the post always appear as defined by page's `<title>` tag/`<meta type="description">` tag.

Can't the contents of facebook post be changed by using facebook's open graph description(`og:description`)/title(`og:title`) tags in the page being posted?

Comment: I'm confused by these two statements:  First you state a fact "but the contents of the post always appear as defined by page's title tag/meta description tag."  Then you ask if the same thing can be done: "Can't the contents of facebook post be changed by using open graph description/title tags in the page being posted?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The title can be changed using og:title as long as the page has less than 50 likes (otherwise it is locked in by Facebook).  The og:description can be changed at any time.

See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/